# FreeBSD POSIX C Oracle API

Tags: c, oracle, api, posix, freebsd

I have trouble finding Oracle Call Interface for FreeBSD. I maybe missing something simple but I searched net for several days and finally ended up here with question.

My task is fairly simple: write a program in posix C that connects to an Oracle database and works on a FreeBSD machine. In worst case scenario I will drop the POSIX and FreeBSD part and make it work on Linux but so far my goal is to do this on BSD. Here is what I found so far:

ftp://ftp.atnet.ru/pub/OS/FreeBSD/oracle/otl/otl.htm

A GNU library which I have not tested yet, if anybody knows anything about it please do tell so:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/orclib/files/OCILIB%20Sources/3.12.1/

If you have any kind of suggestion of how this could be done better please do tell. Or even better if you have experience in this situation.

Comment: AFAIK oracle does not support FreeBSD. This means that oracle libraries are not guaranteed to work on that platform. So, in that sense you are treading on thin ice. How are you planning to connect to the DB?  ODBC?

Comment: @jimmcnamara: As the OP mentions OCI, I suspect the connection shall be done via OCI.

Comment: @jim mcnamara the connector to the Oracle database ideally is supposed to be a module of a larger software that is already running and in production. That is why I am stuck with FreeBSD plus trying to connect with some oracle library working on it, even if it not official.

Comment: OCI requires a transport like SQLNET.  And it requires the oracle libraries - e.g., libclntsh.so and company, be resident on the local box.  This is the reason I'm asking. You have to know how that is set up before trying to get an API working.  And I'd guess it was ODBC. OCI is really a programming interface, old though it is.

Comment: @jimmcnamara thanks for all your effort but we got the scheme working without writing new API, we got mysql as intermediate base which is connected with ODBC to oracle. This is a great downgrade with performance perspective, but it works fine and is easy for the old staff to administer. Thanks for your help and attention everyone.

Comment: How do I close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle themselves do not support FreeBSD. There are ports of their Linux client-libraries, however, that are made to work on the OS:

- [databases/oracle8-client](http://www.freshports.org/databases/oracle8-client)
- [databases/oracle7-client](http://www.freshports.org/databases/oracle7-client)

Unfortunately, the above two are currently only working on i386, but you *may* be able to use the same technique as the port's author to massage the x86_64 Linux binaries to work under FreeBSD/amd64.

And then there is a port of the open-source ODBC driver in:

- [databases/oracle_odbc_driver](http://www.freshports.org/databases/oracle_odbc_driver)

This one requires oracle8-client and is thus also i386-only at this time.

Answer (score 1):

There is oracle instance client for Mac OS X. AFAIK Mac OS somehow related to FreeBSD codebase. So, perhaps, adaptation of Mac OS client would be easier then Linux one. (I didn't try it however).